# Cannot change instance variables in anonymous block (Swift/Parse.com)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, anonymous-function, instance-variables

Parse Data is a a `PFObject` class that contains the "Companies" data that I'm querying. Getting the data and assigning it as a `ParseData` object works fine, but the problem is putting it into my `list`ivar. As you can see from the output, none of the ivars are changing in the anonymous block. Is there a workaround or solution for this?

```
import Foundation
class AllCompanies: NSObject {
    var list:[ParseData] = []
    var testList:[String] = []
    var testString:String = "butter"

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        getCompanies()
    }

    func getCompanies()
    {
        let query = ParseData.query()!
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
            if error == nil
            {
                for company in objects!
                {
                    let newCompany:ParseData = ParseData()
                    newCompany.name = company.objectForKey("Name") as! String
                    newCompany.logo = company.objectForKey("Logo") as! PFFile

                    self.list.append(newCompany)
                    self.testList.append("here")
                    self.testString = "no matter"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error: \(error) \(error?.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method call:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
Parse.setApplicationId("m0zIvk7nfP6nEUrGYzyecbhRdqTrhbUoBI00fvZ4", clientKey: "lmqPfyrkeq4p8v6cukV7aFCVdi4evb8MFyjgvnEG")
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        let allCompanies = AllCompanies()
        print("\(allCompanies.list)")
        print("\(allCompanies.testList)")
        print("\(allCompanies.testString)")
        return true
}
```

Comment: It's better with code in the question rather than screenshots. Also have you actually checked your for loop runs at all?

Comment: The loop does run. Sorry I'll change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCompanies` method is asynchronous ? you make sure whether run your `print` command before `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method.You can't write your asynchronous code as a synchronized code. try to write your print code below `self.testString = "no matter"`.good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the query is asynchronous.

you should move your printing line into the query callback closure.